# Multiple 2 columns in Google sheets that are fed from a google form

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I am trying to multiply 2 columns that are fed from a google form (Probability & Impact from a Risk) to give overall exposure.

I am playing with an ArrayFormula but getting very stuck...

I want to multiply column G by H and output to I

[image: image of sheets]

Thanks

Comment: Please add the code that you had written so others can assist you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this on the cell `I2`:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(G2:G),G2:G*H2:H,))`

Comment: =ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK($G$2:$G),"",$G2*$H2))     This just returns the value for the first row (12)

Comment: @user1699553 You've commented on an answer, not the question. Anyway, the reason that didn't work is because all the parameters need to be ranges, including the `G2` and `H2`.